# XMPP library with support for XEP-133 (admin commands)

Tags: java, php, python, xmpp

I'm trying to get a list of online users from our jabber server, together with their IP addresses. [XEP-133](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html) provides 2 methods I can use for that: `get-online-users-list` and `get-user-stats`.

Now my problem is finding a library (PHP, Python, Ruby, Java) that implements that, but fail to find one.

I tried JAXL v2 which provides basic XEP-133 support, but not enough for this methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't this just require support for the ad-hoc protocol in [XEP-50](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html)?

Comment: Maybe, but my server sends a form with some form values I need to fill. Just having XEP-50 support would miss those IMO.

Comment: Forms are defined in [XEP-4](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0004.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit [XEP-0133](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html) support should be unneccessary. XEP-133 merely defines a set of commands and what they do on the server side. To use these, you need a library which is compliant with [XEP-0050](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html), [XEP-0004](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0004.html) and possibly others.

One of these is [SleekXMPP](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP), which is an asynchronous XMPP client and component library for python. It is acceptably well documented. Just make sure you use a late version from the github repository, as for others the online tutorials are likely to fail (many are using features which were only recently introduced into SleekXMPP).

You might want to look at the [documentation of the xep_0050](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/sleekxmpp/plugins/xep_0050/adhoc.py) and [the source of the xep_0004](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/tree/develop/sleekxmpp/plugins/xep_0004/dataforms.py) plugin

Comment: @cweiske: hi from prosody@conference.prosody.im :)

Comment: Also, there is the sleek@conference.jabber.org room for any SleekXMPP help.

Comment: @cweiske: For what it's worth, I've added a XEP-0133 plugin to Sleek in the master and develop branches which makes the initial XEP-0050 calls. There is also a demo in the examples: https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/master/examples/admin_commands.py

Answer (score 2):

[Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/Form.html) has support for both [Data Forms](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/Form.html) and [Adhoc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/commands/package-summary.html) as well if you are interested in a Java solution.  As has been mentioned, you don't need explicit support so any library that supports these 2 extensions should suit your needs.

Of course if you go with that, then answers such as this supports that (like my own) are all in fact correct but your question kind of falls into the domain of ongoing debate and discussion for all the "me too" answers.